# avoid tooltip linking line in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip, scatter-plot

Consider the following [script](http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/20/):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                lineWidth:1,
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    symbol:'circle',
                    fillColor: '#800000'
                },
            }
        },
  tooltip: {
            enabled:true,
            formatter: function() {
            return "<b>"+this.y+"</b>";
                },
        positioner: function () {
            return { x: 80, y: 50 };
        },
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        color: "#b0b0b0",
        data: [[38,42],[39,39],[35,45],[35,54],{x:36,y:35}]
        }, {
        name: 'B',
        color: "#b0b0b0",
        data: [[46,56],[47,67],[48,69],[50,55],{x:52,y:57}]
    }]
});
var chart=$('#container').highcharts();
});
```

Hovering a data point, it appears a line linking it with its tooltip. If I comment the last line (`var chart=$('#container').highcharts();`) the linking line disappears, but I need to instance the chart.
Is it possible to avoid such linking line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `shape` of your `tooltip`.

By default, the shape is `callout`, which results in the pointer from the tooltip to the data point.

If you set the shape to `square` instead, you will not have the connecting line:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  shape: 'square',
  formatter: function() {
    return "<b>" + this.y + "</b>";
  },
  positioner: function() {
    return {
      x: 80,
      y: 50
    };
  },
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/1wfotmoa/26/

This avoids changing the `border` or `shadow` properties, so you are free to style those elements however you want.

Answer (score 1):

I change inside the tooltip the shape to rect.Check this:

```js
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
   type: 'scatter',
  },
  plotOptions: {
   scatter: {
    lineWidth:1,
    marker: {
     radius: 1,
     symbol:'circle',
     fillColor: '#800000'
    },
   }
  },
  tooltip: {
   enabled:true,
           positioner: function () {
            return { x: 38, y: 43 };
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
        shape: 'rect'
        },
 series: [{
  name: 'A',
  color: "#b0b0b0",
  data: [[38,42],[39,39],[35,45],[35,54],{x:36,y:35}]
  }, {
  name: 'B',
  color: "#b0b0b0",
  data: [[46,56],[47,67],[48,69],[50,55],{x:52,y:57}]
 }]
});
var chart=$('#container').highcharts();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid tooltip linking by setup this two property `shadow: false,` and         `borderWidth: 0,` inside tooltip.

Please refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/25/).